# Windows CMD Batch file to start program and iterativley echo input to its stdin (piping)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, tcp, cmd, pipe

I need to send a TCP message repeatedly, e.g. every 500 ms.
Socat is available for win32 and accepts data from stdin, but afaik it does not support iteration/looping.
A batch file ideally would start the program and then somehow `echo` strings (with newline) into the running program's input.
I am not familiar with piping, if that's the underlying task.

It would be also acceptable to run the program for every iteration (connect, send, discard/ignore reply, disconnect, .. repeat).

```
socat tcp:localhost:8080 -

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO (
  echo "command\n"
)
```

---

Edit: The code above does not work, of course: it never reaches the loop, as socat is waiting for input.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work

Comment: `echo`s always end with newlines, which is convenient since `\n` is the literal string \n in batch and not a newline character.